# How to read empty, but formated, Excel cells with Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a method for reading Excel cells using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), and it works fine. Well... almost fine.

```
public static ArrayList readXLsXFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        ArrayList outListaExcel = new ArrayList();

        FileInputStream fis;
        ptxf= new FileInputStream(pathToExcelFile);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(ptxf);
        XSSFSheet sheetAr = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator rowsAr = sheetAr.rowIterator();
        while (rowsAr.hasNext()) {
            XSSFRow row1 = (XSSFRow) rowsAr.next();
            Iterator cellsAr = row1.cellIterator();
            ArrayList<String> arr;
            arr = new ArrayList();
            while (cellsAr.hasNext()) {
                XSSFCell cell1 = (XSSFCell) cellsAr.next();
                arr.add(String.valueOf(cell1));
            }
            outListaExcel.add(arr);
        }
        return outListaExcel;
    }
```

If cells are formatted, for example if whole A column have borders, then it will keep reading empty cells giving me empty strings. How to ignore those empty(formated) cells?

So `readXLsXFile` will give me an `ArryList` with

```
[0] -> [1][2]
[1] -> [3][4]
```

But it will also give ten more nodes with  empty strings,because coloumn A is formated with borders.

[image]

**edit** after **Gagravarr** answer.

I can avoid checking wether `subList` is empty and then do not add it to `mainList`. But in the case of some very large .xls files and if there is many of them it will take too long, and generaly I think it is not a good practice.

My question was if there is something for **rows**, like it is for **cells** that I have overlooked.

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>mainLista = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
        Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
        int lastColumn = r.getLastCellNum();
        ArrayList<String> subList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
            Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

            if (c != null) {
                subList.add(c.getStringCellValue());
            } else {
            }
        }
        if (!subList.isEmpty() ){  // I think it is not good way
        mainLista.add(subList);}   // to do this, because it still reads 
    }                              // an empty rows
```

Comment: You can `continue` when the text (or other value based on type) is empty. Not sure what you mean exactly.

Comment: @GáborBakos I have edited my question, hope now I make my self clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [Apache POI Documentation on Iterate over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator), the iterators only give you the rows and cells which are defined and have/had content.

If you want to fetch cells with full control over blank or empty cells, you need to instead use something like:

```
// Decide which rows to process
int rowStart = Math.min(15, sheet.getFirstRowNum());
int rowEnd = Math.max(1400, sheet.getLastRowNum());

for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
   Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

   int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT);

   for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
      Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
      if (c == null) {
         // The spreadsheet is empty in this cell
      } else {
         // Do something useful with the cell's contents
      }
   }
}
```

If you want to fetch blank cells (typically those with styling but no values), play with the other Missing Cell Policies, eg [RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK)

Comment: Thanks! I have try that, and try to change MissingCellPolices etc...
It doesnt work, because cells will be "skiped" as if they are non exsisting, but rows will still be there, so the program will continue to read "empty" rows. I can handle them with some ugly hack, but I would like to skip those rows. Because even if they dont  have contents in cells, they have some value. 
In my case "outListaExcel" will have zilion nodes, with zilion "arr" zero size nodes.

Comment: Why not buffer a row's values, and then skip adding it if everything is empty for that row and you don't care about the formatting?

Comment: I can do that, but I think it is not a good practice. Because in case of very large files and if they are too many of them, it would be good idea to buffer every empty cell. Btw, I didn't figure out the way to check for row if it has no content, without to check every cell. On Apache POI documentation, I saw only what you have already post.

Comment: You only buffer one row at a time. If it's empty, throw it away. If it has content, process it as normal?

Comment: How to check weather row is empty without cheking cells ?

Comment: It all depends on how you define empty!

Comment: Well, I have alredy told you. Empty cell in this case means that they have no content in it, but they are formated with borders or some other way. And I have posted a picture to make my self more clearer.

Comment: Then do as I've already suggested, fetch them as normal, and if all the cells in the row are blank (not null and not holding data), just throw away the row's data and don't save it

Answer (score 0):

set the border for column B, in my case it helped me